# How to process multiple commands at once for a Discord Bot (discord.py)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have a discord bot but when, for example, I do /role-all, I cannot use any other command while the role-all command is in progress. How do I make the bot able to process multiple commands at the same time?
I already tried searching google but I don't know the best keywords because I don't know the expression for it.
If you could help me I would appreciate it.
my bot.py file contains the backup command, when i run it i cant use any other command untill its finished.

```
@tree.command(name = "backup", description = "backup the members")
async def backup(interaction: discord.Interaction,limit: int):
    timetowait = limit + 10
    if interaction.user.id == owner:
      await interaction.response.defer()
      count = gettokencount()
      addguild(interaction.guild.id, limit)        
      embed = discord.Embed(title='', description=f"""
**✅ | Members restored**
≡ | restored : {limit}
""", color=5763719)
      await interaction.followup.send(embed=embed)
    else:
        await interaction.response.send_message('you dont have the perms.')
```

my addguild function.

````
def addguild(guild_id, limit):
  print(guild_id)
  conn = mysql.connector.connect(
      host='localhost',
      database='mydb',
      user='mydbuser',
      password=os.environ.get('databasepass'))

  if conn.is_connected():
      amount = 0
      mycursor = conn.cursor()
      sqli = f"SELECT * FROM ..."
      mycursor.execute(sqli)
      toks = mycursor.fetchall()
      for token in toks:
        rand = random.randint(1,5)
        if amount >= int(limit):
            pass 
        else:
            amount += 1
            id = token[1]
            ref = token[0]
            try:
                tokenObject = client.refresh_token(ref)
                ref_token = tokenObject.refresh_token
                sqlf = f"""UPDATE ...
                          SET refresh_token = '{ref_token}', id = '{id}'
                          WHERE id = '{id}'"""
                mycursor.execute(sqlf)
                conn.commit()
            except: 
                sqlp = f"""DELETE FROM ... WHERE id = '{id}'"""
                mycursor.execute(sqlp)
                conn.commit()
                pass
            try:
                tokenObject.join_guild(guild_id, id)
                time.sleep(rand)
            except Exception:
                amount -= 1
                continue
    ```
````

Comment: Instead of including a useless codeblock, include the code of your `role-all` command so we can tell you what's wrong..... The quality standard is there for a reason...

Answer (score 0):

Your code is **blocking**.

Any piece of code that is not asynchronous will block the event loop, so nothing else can run. if your `role-all` command is doing things like non-async API calls (using `requests`) or looping over huge lists, then your whole bot will freeze until the command is done.

See the FAQ for more details: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#what-does-blocking-mean

Take a look at your code, see if anything is heavy/slow & not async, and make it async. For example, the FAQ mentions two common causes, being `time.sleep()` and `requests`. If you're using either of them, there is your problem.

Comment: thx, but i use a database connection, how do i make it a coroutine?

Comment: By using an asynchronous database driver... `asyncpg` for Postgres, `aiosqlite` for SQLite, `motor` for Mongo, ...